# Install 2 separated NuGet packages with one dependency but different versions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, serilog, nuget-package-restore

I want to Install [Serilog.Sinks.Seq 5.2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Seq/5.2.1)
It has a dependency on [Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching 3.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching/3.1.0)

In our Staging area, we also want to use [Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch 9.0.0-beta7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch/9.0.0-beta7)
but this Sink has a dependency on [Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching 2.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching/2.1.1)

and according to [this PR](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch/pull/423), Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching 2.1.1...3.1.0 has a lot of breaking changes.

How can we install these packages side by side and resolve DLL Hell?

Comment: I'd be looking on the ElasticSearch Sink repo whether there's a new version incoming and/or spiking an update PR to see whether the changes break it and/or its tests

Answer (score 1):

You can not use two versions of the same NuGet package in a single project, but I assume you already know that. Separate your code into multiple projects. For example, use one version of the packages in one of your projects and another version in another project. I know this answer is too generic, but this is the best I can give you without more information.